# Generate oAuth nonce for parallel requests

Tags: node.js, api, oauth

I am requesting Bitstamp API in parrallel:

```
// Simplified version

var async = require('async');
var bitstamp = require('bitstamp');

async.parallel([
    bitstamp.balance,
    bitstamp.ticker
    // ...
],
function() (err, result) {
    // process results
});
```

Those two methods are sending signed requests to Bitstamp API including **nonce**.

> Nonce is a regular integer number. It must be increasing with every request you make. Read more about it here. Example: if you set nonce to 1 in your first request, you must set it to at least 2 in your second request. You are not required to start with 1. A common practice is to use unix time for that parameter.

Underlying library generates nonce traditional way:

```
var nonce = new Date().getTime() + '' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
```

### Problem

Because of asynchronous API calls, sometimes nonce generated it very same millisecond, while remote side wants them increasing.

### Question

Keeping parallel requests, any idea to reliably generate sequential nonce?

My obvious try to:

```
this.nonce = new Date().getTime() + '' + new Date().getMilliseconds(); 
// ... on request
var nonce = this.nonce++;
```

But it doesn't solve the problem, same millisecond just increased by one, but still equal.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

npm nonce module is now generate it correctly

Comment: Which npm module?

Answer (score 4):

(author of the npm module here)

I solved it by adding my own counter at the end of the ms timestamp. It now supports up to 999 calls per ms [because of this function](https://github.com/askmike/bitstamp/blob/master/bitstamp.js#L78). The first time it will generate something like `1409074885767000` and if you need a new nonce during the same ms it will then generate `1409074885767001`, `1409074885767002`, ...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, so I took askmike's code and modified it slightly.

```
var nonce = new (function() {

    this.generate = function() {

        var now = Date.now();

        this.counter = (now === this.last? this.counter + 1 : 0);
        this.last    = now;

        // add padding to nonce
        var padding = 
            this.counter < 10 ? '000' : 
                this.counter < 100 ? '00' :
                    this.counter < 1000 ?  '0' : '';

        return now+padding+this.counter;
    };
})();
```

use it like this

```
nonce.generate();
```

check out my [jsfiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ley/utaz9w0z/1/)