# Generated nonce length is getting changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cryptography, nonce

I am trying to generate fixed length nonce (length 9).
But my code is printing sometimes nonce of 8 length and sometime 9 length.

[this](https://github.com/askmike/bitstamp/blob/master/bitstamp.js#L78) is what I am trying to do but with different approach (I have modified it for fixed nonce length)

I am not able to understand why it is printing nonce of length 8 when i am passing length as 9 as argument??

It would be great if someone can tell why this is happening.

Below is complete Nodejs code

```
var last_nonce = null;
var nonce_incr = null;
// if you call new Date to fast it will generate
// the same ms, helper to make sure the nonce is
// truly unique (supports up to 999 calls per ms).
module.exports = {
    getNonce: function(length) {
        if (length === undefined || !length) {
            length = 8;
        }
        var MOD = Math.pow(10, length);
        var now = (+new Date());
        if (now !== last_nonce) {
            nonce_incr = -1;
        }
        nonce_incr++;
        last_nonce = now;
        var nonce_multiplier = ((nonce_incr < 10) ? 10 : ((nonce_incr < 100) ? 100 : 1000));
        var s = (((now % MOD) * nonce_multiplier) + nonce_incr) % MOD;
        return s;
    }
}
//test code
if(require.main === module) {
    console.time("run time");
    //importing async module
    var async = require('async');
    var arr = [];
    //generating 1000 length array to use it in making 1000 async calls
    //to getNonce function
    for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) arr.push(i);
    //this will call getNonce function 1000 time parallely
    async.eachLimit(arr, 1000, function(item, cb) {
        console.log(module.exports.getNonce(9));
        cb();
    }, function(err) {console.timeEnd("run time");});
}
```

Sample output:

```
708201864  --> nonce length 9
708201865
708201866
70820190   --> nonce length 8 (why it is coming 8?? when passed length is 9)
70820191
70820192
70820193
70820194
70820195
70820196
70820197
70820198
70820199
708201910
708201911
708201912
708201913
708201914
708201915
708201916
708201917
708201918
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220393/generate-oauth-nonce-for-parallel-requests (this is what I am trying to do but little with different approach)

Comment: https://github.com/askmike/bitstamp/blob/master/bitstamp.js#L78 actual code is here. I have modified it for fixed nonce length

Comment: It's not a nonce if you wrap it around with small modulus. Anyway, one error that I see is that it should be `var nonce_multiplier = ((nonce_incr < 10) ? 1000 : ((nonce_incr < 100) ? 100 : 10));`. Also, how do you want to handle leading zeros, because they will change the "nonce" length occasionally?

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB. for pointing out leading zero case that is what I have missed here.
I had requirement of fixed length nonce that is why i had put it inside modulus.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs it, here is a nonce generator free from convoluted logic, allowing you to control both character sample and nonce size:

```js
const generateNonce = (options) => {
  const {
    length = 32,
    sample = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
  } = options || {};
  const getRand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * sample.length);
  return Array.from({ length }, () => sample.charAt(getRand())).join('');
};
```

If you prefer Typescript:

```js
const generateNonce = (options?: { sample?: string, length?: number }) => {
  const {
    length = 32,
    sample = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
  } = options || {};
  const getRand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * sample.length);
  return Array.from({ length }, () => sample.charAt(getRand())).join('');
};
```